# ISC-DHCP-SERVER failed, but issues IP fine

Tags: response, dhcp, ipxe

I am running a PXE service on buster.

On a client it searches for a DHCP server, for about a minute.  Then eventually times-out.
Meanwhile on the server `sudo systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service` reports …`Active: failed (Result: exit-code`)… .  Then I issue `sudo systemctl restart isc-dhcp-server.service` - reply: `Job for isc-dhcp-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.`… .

However back on the client, I restart it and again it searches for a DHCP server.  In a second or two it is assigned an IP … (This happens on each boot - as it should.)

So in order to discover more, on the server, `sudo systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service` gives me the PID. Then `journalctl _PID=<PID>` gives all the messages: `… DHCPINFORM from x.y.z.xx via wlan0` and `… DHCPACK to x.y.z.xx (a:b:c:d:e:f) via wlan0` - over and over.

- Are there really errors?
- Why does the daemon report **failed** (with non-error responses) when it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to figure out what is going on with your DHCP server first and why it isn't reporting good status.  Run this command to get the journal entries as to why it is failing as a good start:
journalctl -u isc-dhcp-server

Comment: This is a good answer.  Checking the logs for the pid rather than the service might miss that systemd is restarting the service repeatedly for some reason, where this will tell you why.  If the service is working bet getting restarted, it will sometimes work and then not work while it is being restarted or timing out or whatever is going on.